# Cannot get attribute in laravel accessor (October CMS)

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm currently working on a project with October CMS, and trying to use taglist with relation data.
And I'm using custom accessor to get full name from two columns, seems like a very common case.

But I just couldn't get the model's attributes in the accessor.

Here's my code...

```
class NameOfClass extends Model
{
    /** ALL THE CODE GENERATED BY OCTOBER CMS PLUGIN BUILDER */

    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->firstname." ".$this->lastname;
    }
}
```

And call the accessor in `field.yml` file...

```
fieldName:
  label: FieldName
  descriptionFrom: description
  type: taglist
  mode: relation
  nameFrom: full_name
  customTags: false
```

I can see the accessor gets called just fine, since I can get the value by changing the returned value to plain string.

I've been spent a lot of time researching for solution... any idea?

I'm developing with the official octobercms docker image latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible due to internal code. so I suggest do not try to solve it. its not solvable :) try alternative

> **WHY ??**

Because from code taglist is designed in a such way that it will work with `TAGS`.
it will `allow to create new tags` if there are `no selected tag` and if tags are existing then it will `attache` to given record. and this all will work with `real attributes`.

so its not design to work with virtual attributes.

> For more details this is the code how it generates tags

```php
public function getFieldOptions()
{
    $options = $this->formField->options();

    if (!$options && $this->mode === static::MODE_RELATION) {
        $options = RelationBase::noConstraints(function () {
            $query = $this->getRelationObject()->newQuery();

            // Even though "no constraints" is applied, belongsToMany constrains the query
            // by joining its pivot table. Remove all joins from the query.
            $query->getQuery()->getQuery()->joins = [];

            return $query->lists($this->nameFrom); // <==== LOOK HERE
        });
    }

    return $options;
}
```

You can see this `nameFrom` is directly passed to query and `query/sql` do `not know about our virtual field` so it wont work.

> Alternatively you can use `RelationController Behaviors`
> ref: https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#introduction

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Ahh... I see, I was hoping there's some easier way to make the taglist works for my purpose. But it all make sense now. Thanks man!

Comment: yes if, it would be tags then its perfect fit but for others either need to user `real attribute` and `record can be created by name only no other field required (like tag)` scheme or relation controller  :)